# No of months between 2 dates in node.js

Tags: node.js

The following is the 2 dates from which i have to find the no of months.

```
Sun Mar 01 2015 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (IST)
Tue Sep 01 2015 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (IST)
```

I searched a lot ,but none is representing the above format.Help me to solve this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var date = new Date('Sun Mar 01 2015 05:30:00 GMT+0530');

var date1 =  new Date('Tue Sep 01 2015 05:30:00 GMT+0530');

var diff = date1.getMonth() - date.getMonth();

console.log(diff)
```